# Displaying results from Pivot query in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, pivot-table

I have two tables like this:

**BloodTest**

```
testid, testname
```

**Sample**

```
sampleid, testid, testresult, testdate
```

My query using a Pivot is:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT testdate, testname, testresult 
FROM BloodTest 
NATURAL JOIN Sample
PIVOT (MAX(testresult) FOR testname IN ('Na', 'K')));
```

This produces the correct output like:

```
testdate           'Na'           'K'
2015-01-01         140            4.1
2015-01-02         137            3.8
```

I can't figure out how to display this in ColdFusion though - I get results saying that `testresult` is undefined.  I'm also not sure how to get the testresults to display horizontally in the CF table.

Here is the CF code:

```
    <cfquery name="get_records"
      datasource="#Request.DSN#" username="#Request.usrname#" password="#Request.pwd#">
      SELECT * FROM (SELECT testdate, testname, testresult FROM BloodTest NATURAL JOIN Sample) PIVOT (MAX(testresult) FOR testname IN ('Na', 'K'))
    </cfquery>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Na</th>
        <th>K</th>
      </tr>

    <cfoutput query="get_records">
      <tr>
        <td>#testdate#</td>
        <td>#testresult#</td>
        <td><!-- how to get 2nd testresult here --></td>
      </tr>
    </cfoutput>
```

The error I get is:

Variable TESTRESULT is undefined.

```
The error occurred in /data/coldfusion11/cfusion/wwwroot/blood.cfm: line 37
35 :           <tr>
36 :             <td>#testdate#</td>
37 :             <td>#testresult#</td>
38 :           </tr>
39 :         </cfoutput>
```

Comment: *testresult is undefined.* It would help to see a cfdump of the cfquery and the code used to output the query results

Comment: Added some additional info

Comment: Since you are using PIVOT, the results will be contained in the column names: "K" and "NA" (not "testresult").  So you need to use those column names instead ie  `#NA#` and `#K#`.

Answer (score 4):

Ironically, this morning I showed the following technique to a co-worker who is learning CF.

```
 <cfquery name="pivotQueryData">
 sql goes here
 </cfquery>
```

Now we'll output this to an html table.

```
<cfoutput>
<table>
<tr>
<cfloop array="#pivotQueryData.getcolumnlist()#" index="header">
<th>#Header#</th>
</cfloop>
</tr>

<cfloop query="pivotQueryData">
<tr>
<cfloop array="#pivotQueryData.getcolumnlist()#" index="field">
<td>#pivotQueryData[field][currentrow]#</td>
</cfloop>
</tr>
</cfloop>
</table>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Yes, since the resulting column names from a PIVOT *could* contain invalid characters, using associative array notation is a good approach. Keep in mind `query.getColumnList()` is undocumented.  Another alternative is the core function [`GetMetaData(query)`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/getmetadata.html). It returns an array of structures containing details about the query columns: *IsCaseSensitive,Name,TypeName*.